# How i can do this in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

so in my assignment i have to make this screen in flutter i did this so far but we havent learned much they said search for answers and i cant find everything

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cupertino_icons/cupertino_icons.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Chat App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1.0)),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Person'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => 0,
        ),
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/background.png'))),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                '',
              ),
              Text(
                '',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1.0),
        onPressed: () => 0,
        tooltip: 'Record',
        child: const Icon(Icons.mic),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I did try to do it but I cannot get to know how to add the icons in the appbar and the texts and text field so if anyone could help that would be amazing

Comment: it's the basic things, you better read Flutter documentation first. https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/basics

Answer (score 1):

answering your question quickly!
in AppBar use ListTile as a Widget in the title property and add leading and title inside ListTile.
To achieve action buttons, need to use action property in appbar then you can add IconButton.

Also take a look at widget [catelogue](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/material)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row on `title` and `actions` for right buttons.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () => 0,
    ),
    title: Row(
      children: [
        CircleAvatar(),
        Text(widget.title),
      ],
    ),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Find more about [`AppBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)